# Handling of non breaking space: <p>&nbsp;</p> vs. <p> </p>

Tags: html, css, space

`&nbsp;` is a non breaking space, which represents an empty space where no line break occurs.

If I use

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I have a space between two passages (bigger break). If I use

```
<p> </p>
```

I only have a new line between the two passage (no break). Why?

Comment: Part of the problem is that you want to create an empty paragraph element between paragraphs, while the correct way to get a spacing between them is to use CSS.

Comment: Or `<br />` but since the code is generated from a WYSISWG editor I don't have so much influence on it.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In HTML, elements containing nothing but normal whitespace characters are considered empty. A paragraph that contains just a normal space character will have zero height. A non-breaking space is a special kind of whitespace character that isn't considered to be insignificant, so it can be used as content for a non-empty paragraph.

Even if you consider CSS margins on paragraphs, since an "empty" paragraph has zero height, its vertical margins will [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). This causes it to have no height and no margins, making it appear as if it were never there at all.

Comment: Empty means that this element will not be represented?

Comment: it will be represented, but it will not ocuppy space, since it has 0 height.

Comment: @Nik-Lz it's still present in the DOM, which is what I take "represented" to mean.

Answer (score 7):

How about a workaround?
In my case I took the value of the textarea in a jQuery variable, and changed all **`"<p>&nbsp"`** to **`<p class="clear">`** and clear class to have certain height and margin, as the following example:

**jQuery**

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
var val = $('textarea').val();
val = val.replace(/<p>&nbsp/g, '<p class="clear">');
```

the val is then saved to the database with the new val.

**CSS**

```
p.clear{height: 2px; margin-bottom: 3px;}
```

You can adjust the height & margin as you wish.
And since 'p' is a *display: block* element. it should give you the expected output.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your issue this should work

&emsp—the em space; this should be a very wide space, typically as much as four real spaces.
&ensp—the en space; this should be a somewhat wide space, roughly two regular spaces.
&thinsp—this will be a narrow space, even more narrow than a regular space.

Sources: http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/html-sentences.html