# &nbsp; ignoring whitespace and not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to increase the space between the image and text in this link top bar.

Link: https://pushdaddy2.myshopify.com/

I tried `&nbsp;` which is normal to use for increasing the whitespace but it just prints the `&nbsp;` character.

```
  <span id="pab_message" style="color:inherit;">&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;All t-shirts are 15% off </span>
```

Can anyone say is there any criteria to use `&nbsp;`?

Here is the complete html:

```html
<div id="pab_bar" style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 4px 10px;
    left: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; border: none; 
    background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34); color: rgb(255, 246, 169); font-size: 20px; 
    line-height: 25px; font-family: Sacramento;">
    <div id="pab_content" style="text-align:center; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="https://img.pngio.com/truck-icon-myiconfinder-png-of-transportation-vehicles-256_256.png" 
            width="30" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <span id="pab_message" style="color:inherit;">All t-shirts are 15% off </span>
        <img src="" width="30" style="vertical-align:middle">    
        <span style="display:inline-block;">
            <a id="pab_button" style="outline: none; border: none; line-height: 2em; 
                padding: 0px 1em; margin: 0px 0px 0px 1em; display: inline-block; 
                border-radius: 0.25em; cursor: pointer; width: auto;
                height: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 0.875em; 
                text-align: center; text-decoration: none; 
                -webkit-appearance: none; color: rgb(255, 246, 169); 
                background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" type="button" href="#" 
                onclick="pab_button_on_click(event)">Check the product</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's for non-breakable white-space

Comment: Why dont you simply use margin-left: 10px; or padding-left: 10px;

Comment: @EvikGhazarian i dont know what is that space. it may be single space. it may be double triple or anything else so what is the problem in &nbsp; do u have understanding about this ?? why browser is not rendering correctly

Comment: Your _browser_ is rendering it correctly. The example you included uses `&amp;nbsp;`, not `&nbsp;`. Your CMS is probably HTML encoding the ampersand when you enter it.

Comment: I did some formatting and see your image tags are not closed properly.

Comment: @wazz `img` tags are self closing. There is nothing wrong with them.

Comment: @Turnip Tnx. not sure if i ever knew that or completely forgot!

Answer (score 2):

> *"I tried `&nbsp;` which is normal to use for increasing the whitespace but it just prints the `&nbsp;` character."*

**No it's not**, that's what `padding` is for.

```css
#pab_message {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="pab_bar" style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 4px 10px; left: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; border: none; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34); color: rgb(255, 246, 169); font-size: 20px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Sacramento;">
  <div id="pab_content" style="text-align:center; display: inline-block;"><img src="https://img.pngio.com/truck-icon-myiconfinder-png-of-transportation-vehicles-256_256.png" width="30" style="vertical-align:middle"> <span id="pab_message" style="color:inherit;">All t-shirts are 15% off </span><img src="" width="30" style="vertical-align:middle">    <span style="display:inline-block;"><a id="pab_button" style="outline: none; border: none; line-height: 2em; padding: 0px 1em; margin: 0px 0px 0px 1em; display: inline-block; border-radius: 0.25em; cursor: pointer; width: auto; height: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 0.875em; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; -webkit-appearance: none; color: rgb(255, 246, 169); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" type="button" href="#" onclick="pab_button_on_click(event)">Check the product</a></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to give manual space because everytime we dont need same space. we need varying space, sometime one space sometime two space. so we cant use css

Comment: @sonamona You can create classes with relevant styling such as `.space-left-1:padding-left:1rem;`, `.space-left-2:padding-left:2rem;` etc..

Comment: @sonamona `&nbsp;` is the **worst** way to do this. CSS with utility classes or as a last resort, inline CSS is the way to handle it. `margin` is also something to consider depending on the element and design.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing **@Paulie_D**'s answer. And your comment. If you want manual spaces just use inline spacing with different padding values.

```
  <span id="pab_message" style="color:inherit; padding-left: 10px;">All t-shirts are 15% off </span>

  <span id="pab_message" style="color:inherit; padding-left: 15px;">All t-shirts are 15% off </span>

  <span id="pab_message" style="color:inherit; padding-left:20px;">All t-shirts are 15% off </span>
```

**AND** to your answer that why non breaking space doesn't work at the beginning of the sentence you can look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12279649/9357872

or read this from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp:

> Non-breaking Space
>
> A common character entity used in HTML is the non-breaking space:
>
> A non-breaking space is a space that will not break into a new line.
>
> Two words separated by a non-breaking space will stick together (not
>   break into a new line). This is handy when breaking the words might be
>   disruptive.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> § 10
> 10 km/h
> 10 PM
> ```
>
> Another common use of the non-breaking space is to prevent browsers
>   from truncating spaces in HTML pages.
>
> If you write 10 spaces in your text, the browser will remove 9 of
>   them. To add real spaces to your text, you can use the  
>   character entity.